# Set "free shipping" method as selected default shipping option in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm struggling with changing the shipping option selected default. The 'Free shipping' shipping option only shows up if the customer has the amount over $70 + in the cart. If the amount on the cart is less than $70 the shipping option will not show up on the shipping options.

If the customer has over $70 or more, the "Free shipping" option will show up and it should be a default selected shipping option.

I tried adding the following snippet but it seems not working for me or maybe there's a mistake on modifying the ID's(unsure).

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'set_default_chosen_shipping_method', 5 );
function set_default_chosen_shipping_method(){
    //
    if( count( WC()->session->get('shipping_method_0')['rates'] ) > 0 ){
        foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_method_0')['rates'] as $rate_id =>$rate)
            if($rate->method_id == 'free_shipping30'){
                $default_rate_id = array( $rate_id );
                break;
            }

        WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', $default_rate_id );
    }
}
```

I got this snippet idea [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/483014/set-flat-rate-shipping-method-as-default-in-woocommerce)

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: WooCommerce comes with a Free Shipping option with a minimum cart value. There's no need for code. It's built in. 
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping > edit zone > enable free shipping > set minimum order amount to 70

Comment: Understood, I already set up the free shipping and set the minimum order amount.  The only problem I am facing is that, if the customer reaches or surpasses the minimum amount to get the free shipping, the free shipping option should be automatically selected in the shipping options. Right now, it automatically selects the "First-Class Mail" shipping option even if there's a free shipping option available on the shipping options. I hope I explain it well :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes

- Replace `WC()->session->get('shipping_method_0')['rates']` with `WC()->session->get( 'shipping_for_package_0')['rates']`
- Replace `if($rate->method_id == 'free_shipping30'){` with `if ( $rate->method_id == 'free_shipping' ) {`

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_cart() { 
    // NOT empty (get)
    if ( count( WC()->session->get( 'shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] ) > 0 ) {
        // Loop through
        foreach ( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $rate_id => $rate ) {            
            // For free shipping
            if ( $rate->method_id == 'free_shipping' ) {
                $default_rate_id = array( $rate_id );
                break;
            }
        }

        // Set
        WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', $default_rate_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'action_woocommerce_before_cart', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @7uc1f3r does deselect free shipping if available, but also deselects other default shipping methods* if no free shipping is available, resulting in no shipping method being selected.

The following should only affect the default shipping method if there **is** a free shipping method available.

```php
function select_free_shipping_by_default()
{
    if ($rates = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates']) {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            if ($rate->method_id == 'free_shipping') {
                WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array($rate_id));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'select_free_shipping_by_default', 10, 0);
```

Depending on your aesthetic, you could alternatively accomplish this without a the `foreach` loop, though I accept this may be less legible (and would require PHP 7.4+ for the arrow function).

```php
function select_free_shipping_by_default()
{
    if ($rates = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates']) {
        if ($free = array_filter($rates, fn ($x) => $x->method_id == 'free_shipping')) {
            WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array_keys($free));
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'select_free_shipping_by_default', 10, 0);
```

Tested on:  WooComerce 8.3.1 | WordPress 6.4.3 | PHP 8.1.23

Hope this helps someone :)

---

* *The default selection for shipping method is normally configured in the admin. The first item in drag/drop order of the shipping methods in the relevant shipping zone is selected by default (eg at `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping&zone_id=1`).*